# Generate bar graph with one bar per column (convert column to group)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a diagram in R from this test dataset (practice_dataset.csv):

```
genes,cell1,cell2,cell3,cell4
gene1,14,10,20,3
gene2,12,5,3,0
gene3,8.5,3,5,0
gene4,13,0,0,0
gene5,2.5,7.5,1,10
```

I want to display a count of how many genes (gene1-gene5) with a value above 0 that are present for each cell. I'm using colSums(data > 0) to summarize the columns, but I do not understand how to tell R that each column is one group. This is how my code currently looks:

```
setwd("~/.../...")

library(ggplot2)

pdf("testplot.pdf", w=20, h=7)

#Load dataset
data <- read.table("practice_dataset.csv",
                   sep=",",
                   header=TRUE)

# Summarize the number of genes with a value of >0 for each column
genes.no <- colSums(data > 0)

# Generate bar plot with one bar of genes.no per cell/column 
geom_bar(genes.no)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `barplot` from `base R`.  If 'genes' is the first column, we need to remove that column while doing the `colSums` as it is non-numeric (`data[-1]`).   and do the `barplot`.

```
barplot(colSums(data[-1] >0))
```

[image]

---

If we want to do this with `ggplot`, we can convert the 'wide' format to 'long' with `gather` (from `tidyr`), get the `sum` of 'Val' grouped by the 'Var' and use the `ggplot` syntax to get the bar plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(data, Var, Val, -genes)  %>%
          group_by(Var) %>% 
          summarise(Val= sum(Val>0)) %>% 
          ggplot(., aes(x=Var, y=Val)) +
                  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually want to achieve the opposite, i.e. plot how many of gene1-gene5 that have a value >0 in each one of cell1-cell4 (so on x axis there would be cell1, cell2, cell3...), but this is many steps closer to what I want to achieve than where I was stuck! I realise now I should use colsum...

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I needed to update my R version to make tidyr and dplyr work. Now they do, and your solutions work as well, also on my huge datasets. Thank you so much, that was helpful and educating for me to read!